# Group By Issue in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Im having trouble with this query:

```
SELECT a.created_by, 
CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author 
FROM #__content AS a 
LEFT JOIN #__users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by 
WHERE a.state='1' 
GROUP BY a.created_by 
ORDER BY author
```

The results which return are somewhat correct but the issue im having is that its grouping by the ID but its still returning some names repeated (these names are the same but have different ID's).

How can I group these names if they have different ID's?

[image: Here is an example of the code returned]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: GROUP BY a.create_by, author

Comment: I have also tried that and the results which return double, triple and cuadriple when they should be less :S.

Comment: @PLATANIUM would you post output of `    SELECT a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, ua.name
    FROM #__content AS a 
        LEFT JOIN #__users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by 
    WHERE a.state='1' `

Comment: The problem is, create_by and author are 2 different query condition, it's say, each create_by may have multiple autohr, so do reverse, in this schene you can't get result you want. Maybe I misunderstand your point, is SELECT DISTINCT your choice ?

Comment: I have found the issue. Its what Fwolf said. Each user may have multiple aliases so this is where the problem comes. I think I will just make an if statement in the view to print only the names once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by Author too

```
SELECT 
    a.created_by, 
    CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author 
FROM #__content AS a 
LEFT JOIN #__users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by 
WHERE a.state='1' 
GROUP BY a.created_by ,author
ORDER BY author
```

Comment: I have already tried that and for some reason when I group by author it returns alot more results than it should :S.